# How to find out a Domian Registrant Contact

Tags: dns, icann

There is a website using domain name similar to my business domain, However, he is tricking people by have restaurant website and let people transfer money to him online. However, How could I know the domain owner to file a police report where he is filled a wrong info for Registrant contact as shown below:
Registrant Contact
Name: Verve US
Organization: Verve US
Street: 6100 Center Drive Suite 1190
City: Los Angeles
State: CA
Postal Code: 90045
Country: US
Phone: +1.7574166575
Email: xxxx@dns-protect.net

Comment: This sounds like a request for legal or perhaps strategic advice with regard to trademark infringement. It's not about programming, and is therefore off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is about a gTLD domain name (you do not say) you can report suspicion of wrong/invalid data in whois records at https://forms.icann.org/en/resources/compliance/complaints/whois/inaccuracy-form

The sponsoring registrar will then need to conduct a search with the registrant to make sure everything is legit.

There are only two outcomes, besides no change at all: either the whois record gets changed and fixed or the domain name gets deleted.

Now if you have questions about a website legitimacy in selling services or such, you may better approach a customer protection agency or  organization depending on the country you are in, like the BBB.

If you have a dispute on the domain name itself as you believe you have rights on them, again if it is a gTLD, look here:
https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/dndr-2012-02-25-en#udrp
Do not attempt to go further in that procedure without some legal counsel.

You can instead also go the judiciary route (again: do not attempt without consulting some legal counsel or attorney specialized on these issues), which will often start by your counsel written a letter (both postal and email) to the owner's data as written in whois before attempting anything else. Proof of non-deliverability will often lead to domain deletion. But if the problem is on the website the given website could restart seconds later on another domain name.

So you first should be far more clear on what your are speaking about (the domain name or the website?), and what are your goals?

Answer (score 0):

here is a link visit https://www.whois.net/ where you can find the information and the owner name of any domain....

Comment: He is putting a fake info

Comment: this website will tell you complete information about a domain. and you can contact with the registrar.